# Do we need ''from'' after the word ''leave''?

Tags: word-usage

> The river bus leaves from Pier 4.

This sentence is from Oxford Advance Learner Dictionary.
Do we need ''from'' after the word ''leave''?

Comment: For me in British English the "from" is needed. The phrase "The river bus leaves Pier 4" begs the question "When (at what time) does it leave?".

Comment: Consider transitive AND preposition-based forms such as #1 *The train leaves London from Victoria Station* and #2 *The train leaves Victoria Station from platform 3*. The primary object (*London* in #1, *Victoria Station* in #2) is always *the more "general" location*. Essentially, it identifies the starting point from the broader perspective of the entire journey. The "secondary" object (*Victoria Station* in #1, *platform 3* in #2) more precisely identifies the exact location where the act of leaving occurred. Obviously, there can be some overlap, as evidenced by my examples.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _The train leaves Victoria Station_ sounds OK to me because it is such a huge thing. _The river bus leaves pier 4_ does indeed sound like it needs an _at eight am_ as AdrianHHH said

Comment: @mplungjan: I bet if you actually *worked* on the ferries you'd be more inclined to say things like *The ferry just left pier 4*. It's all a matter of perspective, but I'm sure most native speakers would be quite happy with both of my earlier examples. Where *Victoria Station* can be referenced with or without a preposition - depending on its spatial overlap with the other specified location ***if present*** (if not, it's really just a stylistic choice).

Comment: When the ferry leaves the pier, it is leaving a landmass. When the bus is leaving, it is leaving a street

Answer (score -1):

Seldomly, Yes. 'From' before 'leave' is usually found in sentences.

Look at this One.

Jack was *from* Canada, before the *leave*.

Now look at this One.

Jack was to *leave*, from Canada.

They are in the same meaning, but the words are replaced, insuring it's not in a different context.

Therefore, Yes, we can either do from before leave, or leave before from, if we put it into its correct context.